# Make Elasticsearch handle only the numeric part of a string field and parse/copy it into a numeric field

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

In my data, I have a field that contain a string representation of a year. The field can contain other characters and sometimes several year strings.
**Examples:**

```
1995-2000
[2000]
cop. 1865
```

I want to (in Elasticsearch) extract these years and parse them into a numeric (multi-valued) field in order to make Histogram aggregates.

I have tried the following configuration which gives me only the numeric parts of the strings as tokens, but I cannot figure out how to make the final step and have those tokens interpreted as integers/shorts.

```
{
    "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
            "numeric_extractor": {
                "filter": [
                    "numeric_keeper"
                ],
                "tokenizer": "numeric_keeper_tokenizer"
            }
        },
        "char_filter": {
            "non_numeric_remover": {
                "type": "pattern_replace",
                "pattern": "[^0-9]+",
                "replacement": " "
            }
        },
        "tokenizer": {
            "numeric_keeper_tokenizer": {
                "type": "pattern",
                "group": 1,
                "pattern": "([0-9]{4})"
            }
        },
        "filter": {
            "numeric_keeper": {
                "type": "pattern_capture",
                "preserve_original": 0,
                "patterns": [
                    "([0-9]{4})"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "properties": {
        "date": {
            "fields": {
                "date": {
                    "analyzer": "numeric_extractor",
                    "index": "analyzed",
                    "type": "string"
                }
            },
            "type": "multi_field"
        }
    }
}
```

Elastic version 2.4.

Comment: You cannot. Do this parsing outside ES and index the correct values if you want that field to actually be a numeric one.

Comment: Or, inside ES, maybe the ingest node features can help at indexing time: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.3/ingest.html

Comment: Reason wise, i am getting closer and closer to an upgrade to Elasticsearch 5.x.